Why does tensor "transformer_layer_0/BroadcastTo1" have a size and is quantized to a INT32 in tflite?
I produced a GPT2 model using Tensorflow Lite following this tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/codelabs/blob/main/KerasNLP/io2023_workshop.ipynb.
I then visualize the tflite model using tensorflow/lite/tools/visualize.py. I am interested in how different tensors are quantized.
Most of the parameters are quantized to INT8, which is expected. I am confused about two things regarding the following tensors: transformer_layer_0/BroadcastTo, transformer_layer_0/BroadcastTo1, transformer_layer_0/cached_multi_head_attention/ExpandDims, (... for each "transformer_layer").

What does a broadcast/ExpandDims "tensor" store? It seems to me that those are not trainable operations (e.g. doing broadcasting), so why would the tensors have a huge shape [1, 100, 100] (i.e. 10,000 elements)?
Why are those tensors quantized to a higher precision (INT32 vs INT8 like other params)

